# What is the easiest way to copy a nested vector

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor

In my code I have a struct named `bead`. and I have a vector which is defined as

`vector< vector< vector <vector <bead*> > > > boxes`

Sometimes, I need to make some changes to the `boxes` and I might need to revert those changes.

What happen if I do the following:

```
vector< vector <vector <vector <bead*> > > > nBoxes;
nBoxes = boxes;
....
//some code that resizes the forth nest in nBoxes and create new content
....
boxes = nBoxes;
```

Will the data in boxes be changed through changes applied to nBoxes?

here is the definition of bead:

```
struct bead{
  particle mainPart;
  int charge;
  int type;
  double rho;
  double nextRho;
  int LID;
  double U;
  double nextU;
  bool touch;
};
```

which requires the definition of `particle`

```
struct particle{
  vec pos;
  vec oldPos;
  vec vel;
  vec oldVel;
  vec F;
  vec oldF;
};
```

`vec` is a class that hold a velarray parameters along with bunch of functions to manipulate it.

Comment: What on earth is the purpose of all this nesting?

Comment: The _easiest_ way to copy a vector is to, well, copy the vector. Assignment is always a good first bet for copying. Note that you're using naked pointers in a container. Often that's not a good idea. Are those beads dynamically allocated? Who owns them?

Comment: Karl The nesting is for the purpose of stating some are of coordinates x,y,z which holds a vector of n beads. @sbi, yes, the beads are dynamically allocated, they are held in a different vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you meant

```
boxes = nBoxes;
```

in the end.

`operator =` of vector copies the contents of the `vector`. That is, in your case it copies the pointers to `bead`. The bead objects themselves aren't deep-copied.

Comment: So, any changes I make to a bead will be transferred to another vector, but any changes I make to a vector (removing or addin a bead) won't be transferred. Great, that's what I need

Comment: @Yotam: That is exactly what's gonna happen.

Answer (score 2):

The data that is stored in the vector of vector of ... will be copied correctly on your assignement expressions.

BUT the data stored in your vectors is only pointers! Therefore, whenever your changed the `bead` data from one vector, you change it in both, as both vector only contains a pointer to a single memory location.

Answer (score 1):

```
nBoxes = boxes;
```

will make a complete copy of the `boxes` vector. Any changes made to the contents of `nBoxes` will not impact the content of `boxes`.

However : if you make changes to the `bead` objects pointed to by the `bead*` pointers, then those changes will also be seen in the `boxes` vector.
If you want to avoid that, you'll need to make a deep copy of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Is probably a good idea to forget about your nested vectors and implement a custom class that overrides operator= and behaves as you wish (copying sub-vectors)

A second idea is to use `vector< vector< vector <vector <bead> > > > boxes;`

Comment: because is too complex and will be hard to work with it. A custom class is often better in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a reason why a proprietary class with unknown semantics and an arbitrary number of bugs is _necessarily_ better than a well known, if somewhat complex, data structure. It might well be, but then it might not. If anything, I'd recommend using proper typedefs to name those levels of nesting sanely.

Comment: may be a personal preference, but a custom class can "be made" mode friendly than a general one. ex: operator[] to select level